# Not jump to file in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I've been using `Aptana Studio 3` for awhile now and I like it much better than `Dreamweaver`. However, one quirk that's starting to annoying is that if I have a few scripts/documents open from my project, when I click on one of the open tabs the project explorer automatically jumps and selects that file in the list.

This is very annoying when trying to view a list of files in a directory and also trying to type in a script/document that is located in another directory.

So my question is: How do I get `Aptana Studio 3` to not automatically jump to a file like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why this post was voted down. I think people don't like to actually read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

I believe your problem is the 'Link with Editor' option in the Project Explorer. You can find it under the little arrow at the top right of the Project Explorer. Make sure it is turned off.
[image]